# MidiConvert from base64 encoded midi

Tags: javascript, parsing, base64, midi

Is it possible to use the excellent [MidiConvert](https://github.com/Tonejs/MidiConvert) with base64 encoded midi data?

My data look like this:

```
data:audio/midi;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAQAOAeBNVHJrAAAALwD/Awl...
```

I would like to do this in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the following approach, converting the base64-encoded data to a `Blob` such that it can be read with `FileReader`, enabling it to be used with `MidiConvert.parse`:

([live example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbzJwb?editors=1012#0))

```
dataURItoBlob = dataURI => {
  const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

  let ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
};

parseMidiFromDataURI = dataURI => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    const partsData = MidiConvert.parse(e.target.result);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(partsData, undefined, 2));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(dataURItoBlob(dataURI));
};

parseMidiFromDataURI("data:audio/midi;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAAABAeBNVHJrAAAA5wD/WAQEAhgIAP9RAwehIADAAADAAGWQXH8AwABlgFx/AMAAZZBZfwDAAGWAWX8AwABlkFZ/AMAAZYBWfwDAAGWQQ38AkEF/AJBCfwCQQH8AkD9/AMlPAJlPfwDAAACQU38AwABlgEN/AMAAZYBCfwDAAGWAP38AwABlgFN/AMAAZZBDfwDJTwCZT38AwAAAkFB/AMAAZYBBfwDAAGWJT38AwABliQB/AMAAZcAAZYBAfwDAAGWAUH8AwABlkE1/AMAAZYBDfwDAAGXAAGWATX8AwABlwABlwABlwABlwABlkDh/AP8vAA==");
```

Output:

```
{
  "header": {
    "PPQ": 480,
    "timeSignature": [
      4,
      4
    ],
    "bpm": 120,
    "name": ""
  },
  "startTime": 0.10520833333333333,
  "duration": 2.8406249999999984,
  ...
```

Comment: hi cody, I appreciate your help! I'm getting a "str.substr is not a function" error from midiconvert when I run your code. Any idea by any chance?

Comment: @Hoff Hmm, not sure. What browser are you using? Here's a codepen with the complete minimal example that works for me on Chrome 70: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbzJwb?editors=1012#0

Comment: thanks a lot, your code works perfectly! u save my day!